# How to add google api key inside jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am using jQuery Location Picker Plugin. In my case google maps not working. It shows This page can't load Google Maps correctly error. I searched on google and youtube for solving this problem. I have understood that I have to add map api key. But my question is How can I add api key inside this plugin jquery code cause there is no option for adding api key. It has latitude & longitude. I am new at Jquery.
Plugin Url: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Location-Picker-Place-Autocomplete-Plugin-For-Google-Maps-Location-Picker/

```
<script>

    $('#us3').locationpicker({
      location: {
        latitude: 23.707310,
        longitude: 90.415482
      },
      radius: 300,
      inputBinding: {
        latitudeInput: $('#us3-lat'),
        longitudeInput: $('#us3-lon'),
        radiusInput: $('#us3-radius'),
        locationNameInput: $('#us3-address')
      },
      enableAutocomplete: true,
      onchanged: function(currentLocation, radius, isMarkerDropped) {
        // Uncomment line below to show alert on each Location Changed event
        //alert("Location changed. New location (" + currentLocation.latitude + ", " + currentLocation.longitude + ")");
      }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"async defer></script>
```

Add this code above your own.

This page will you help.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key